# Running TestCafe tests as part of CI/CD

Tags: testing, azure-devops, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I created a couple of integration tests using [TestCafe](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe).

Trying to add it as part of my Azure Devops CI/CD pipeline, according to the the [TestCafe docs](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/continuous-integration/azure-devops.html) i should add them to my build pipeline.

My question is why would you run it as part of the build pipeline? 
Surely you would like to run your integration tests against the code that you deployed?

Comment: Which docs do you refer to? Do you mean you want to run TestCafe tests in release pipeline?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT i see that the links to the documentation got removed as part of an edit.

Answer (score 1):

If your pipeline is deploying your app, then yes, you might consider running the integration tests as a release task against the deployed application.

However, if it's possible for a build agent to easily stand up your app during a build (such as using Docker), you could run your integration tests during a build.

It may also be the case that your integration tests validate connectivity to third party systems, and your tests can execute without need for a complete application. For instance if you have DLLs that connect to Microsoft's GraphAPI.

Comment: Lets assume i want to use docker at build time, how would that look? Can you point me to an article maybe. Currently i have several build definitions that forms part of my application. If i had to spin up an container it will only have one section of my site running.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation below, it provides how to integrate TestCafe tests into an Azure DevOps Server and an Azure Pipelines project's build process.

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/continuous-integration/azure-devops.html

The documentation provides both YAML sample and classical build sample. As we know, Release Pipelines can’t be configured by YAML yet, if you want to run TestCafe tests in release pipeline, you may refer to the classic build sample:

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/continuous-integration/azure-devops.html#configure-build-task-on-azure-devops-server

Comment: I did go through the documentation but if i am not mistaken the examples provided runs at build time and not release time. It is also worth nothing that i am deploying to an azure web app. Not sure if you can even run an headless browser in azure. What i ended up doing now is, I just deployed the testcafe artifacts to an azurevm and ran the tests there before i do the actual release.

Comment: I will...just wanted to wait another day to see if someone else might answer